# Visual Studio 2017 add item cross-platform missing

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, visual-studio-2017

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 to follow along with online training for Xamarin created in May. They instructed us to add a new item and then selected Cross-Platform. 
I did not have Cross-Platform as an option. I found a post for an older version of Visual Studio where they showed how to add it manually. I did this and it created the Cross-Platform item but this only contained four options instead of the ten in the video. 
Has this been taken away in a newer release or do I need to do something to add all the items?
Many thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit what items are you talking about (classes, projects, views...)?

Comment: See answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824129/missing-templates-in-latest-xamarin-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Yeah, I do need to explain a bit more. It is not the same templates mentioned there, AQuirky. I have created a Xamarin Cross Platform app, Blank App with Xamarin.Forms and PCL. It has created all the projects and then I right click on the PCL and select Add new item. In the video they have got Cross-Platform on the left with 10 items. I have not got Cross-Platform.

Comment: @S.Roberts Did you ever find a solve?  I have the exact same issue.

Comment: Nope @davecove. I have posted on the Xamarin forums too with no answer. I have also logged an issue with Microsoft and it has been triaged, whatever that means to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a solution. I used the Visual Studio uninstaller to uninstall Mobile Development with .Net, rebooted and then installed it again. Works like a charm. There must have been old versions that were not getting updated or something was corrupt. Hope this helps someone.