# Missing Templates in Latest Xamarin Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I wanted to start Cross Mobile App Development for that I had heard Xamarin is a good framework if you are good with C# , so , I had downloaded the latest Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin module installed, for learning I got the Udemy Course for Xamarin and its the latest one, so my question is in the videos and most of the tutorials out there are many templates which are missing in my Visual Studio so to make it simple I want to ask you guys that am I having the correct templates and the videos I'm referring to are old please clarify them I will post the screenshots of my setup and the video's setup.

**PS. Please excuse my novice I just started it and Google just got me confused  **
Here is my Setup:
[image: New Project Teamplates]

[image: porjectsetup][image: project setup]

[image: Can't find forms native and other templates]

I'm just asking since to learn I need to have the same setup if there's some dissimilarity then I won't be able to have a heads up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off welcome to the Xamarin world.

Secondly your templates that you have are correct. They simply changed up a bit in visual studio 2017. For instance, if you want to create a PCL ( Portable Class Library ) project, you select cross-platform app and click ok. Than you get following screen:
[image: screen]

Here can select your coding strategy ( I chose PCL in screenshot ).

If more questions don't hesistate to ask and goodluck ;)

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for this! , okay now could you elaborate some more terms?
1. Xamarin Forms vs Xamarin Native?
2. Shared Project vs PCL?

Thanks as the tutorials are old and most of the classes are misplaced or are there where I can't see them totally confused.

Comment: This is the post I read to chose between shared project / pcl : https://xamarinhelp.com/portable-class-library-pcl-vs-shared-projects/
Tl;dr:PCL is great way to write code once. Also a thing to note is that pcl uses packages where that shared project uses references. A master detail template is kinda an example app ( with nice structure that you could possibly follow, it's a nice to checkout). For the UI technology part I advise to read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204807/when-to-use-xamarin-forms-vs-xamarin-native . If any other questions, make a chat ;)

Comment: Could you please come over skype? id:saifali9312
that would be a great help senior!

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that atm, I'm able to do that tomorrow though (I pref discord than). There is also a chat option in stackoverflow.Edit: nvm about stackoverflow, you need a rep of 100. Btw if you find my answer correct, don't forget to mark it ;)

Comment: Sure but please do help me it been years and Xamarin is my dream and I think I'm failing it I can;t find nay guide.

Comment: Xamarin is nice but you'll find a lot of challenges on the way, don't hesistate to ask them on here. Also look for package / references, there are amazing community made stuff out there. And yes I will help you, but I can only help you in the weekend i'm afraid. Do you have discord?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147937/discussion-between-jordy-dieltjens-and-saif-ali).

Comment: The problem is Microsoft purchased Xamarin, thats why this answer is no longer correct.

Comment: This was right after they purchased it, but it is indeed possible they updated it. Normally most things stay similar though

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft keep on improving VS and Xamarin. Yesterday I updated VS 2017 to version 15.8.4 and now I see a difference also between your screen Jordy Dieltjens and mine as below, you have "UI Technology" to the left bottom corner and instead I have "Platform". Also you have "Portable Class Library (PCL)" under "Code sharing strategy" to the right bottom corner where I have ".Net Standard" instead. as per my knowledge PCL is now deprecated and replaced with .Net Standard which is supposed to do the same.

[image: Cross Platform options]