# Visual Studio 2017 - Xamarin Native template is missing

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Any help as to why I don't see the Xamarin Native template? I re-installed the Visual Studio & also reinstalled Xamarin work load alone, but with no joy so far.

[image]

[image: VS Info]

Edited:
Why I don't see three options as in this question?
[Missing Templates in Latest Xamarin Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44824129/missing-templates-in-latest-xamarin-visual-studio-2017?rq=1)

if someone can confirm, on their VS2017 15.6.6 that it indeed exists for them, that would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Native template? Native, as in *not* Forms-based?

Comment: I meant, Xamarin.Native and not Xamarin.Forms. That template shows options only for Xamarin.Forms (though the description says that it gives both)

Comment: Look under the `Android` and `iOS` sections on the left hand side, that is where the platform native projects exist. They are not called `Xamarin.Native` (there is no such animal), they are `Xamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android`

Comment: @Jazimov He is looking for the native application projects, i.e NON-Forms-based

Comment: @Jazimov Read the section above what you are quoting... The template you are showing is for `Xamarin.Forms` (shared|NetStd) based, if you go the main template screen and choose iOS or Android, those are the "Native user interface" templates that the section you quoted are referring too.

Comment: @Jazimov with xamarin.forms also we can write platform specific code upon requirement. But I am looking for the other template. I am a seasoned xamarin dev, suddenly I don't see the template. I am afraid if you had any experience with xamarin. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had this - if you are referring to the "complete" template, i.e. new solution with Android, iOS, UWP and a Shared project created for you with all references, then they are in "other".

E.g. Visual C# > Other

Which should give you templates for Blank Cross-Platform Mobile App (Native) as well as Master Detail Cross-Platform Mobile App (Native)

It looks like VS has done away with the old format for now, where you could select the project type as well as the UI approach utilised.

If you get stuck, or on a version of VS that doesn't have this options tree, then type the word 'Native' into the search box in the top right of the first dialog. That's how I eventually found it!

(Using Visual Studio Professional 2017 - Version 15.7.2)

Comment: Great, it is right there under other. However it doesn't prompt to choose between PCL or Shared. The project gets created with 'Shared' Library by default. Any clue?

Comment: For a Native project there is no such thing as a PCL. PCL (or .Net Standard as it is now known) is a share of the UI code as well as a shared code project, which you cannot do in Xamarin Native - Hence why Forms was built.
For a .Net Standard app in Forms, just select the cross platform item from the menu, where you will be presented with the selection once you add the new project name. 
The only choice in Native you now have is between a normal Xamarin Native app, and a Xamarin Native app as a Master Detail template.

Answer (score 1):

For me there was no Visual C# > Other.
So I had click Visual C#, then search mobile (two options show up - one with Xamarin.forms and one Just called Mobile App (the description speaks of Android and iOS) so it has to be this one. And Yes it doesn't prompt for Any other options afterwards.

Comment: This is true - somewhere between 15.7.2 and 15.8.6 the 'Other' option as described above looks to have been removed. I can't find native templates at all now. The 'Mobile' search gives me a mobile app option - but that is still Xamarin Forms with an MvvM example setup added.